# compare two input values using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to compare two values from a dual input range slider. If the bottom value is equal or greater than the top value, I want to return `false`. This is to prevent overlap between the two thumbs.

I have used `.change` to listen for changes. I can then `console.log` & return the value after it's been updated. I have included the last bit of code in the hope for help. You can see an full almost working version here:

https://fiddle.jshell.net/elliottjb7/fj9ot08v/

Thanks

```
$("input[type='range'][id='text_box_bottom_range']").change(function() {
  var bottom = $("input[type='range'][id='text_box_bottom_range']").val();
  console.log("bottom = " + bottom);
  return bottom;
});

$("input[type='range'][id='text_box_top_range']").change(function() {
  var top = $("input[type='range'][id='text_box_top_range']").val();
  console.log("top = " + top);
  return top;
});     

$("input").blur(function() {
  if ($("input[type='range'][id='text_box_bottom_range']").val() > this.val) {
    console.log("Bottom is higher than Top");
    return false;
  } else { 
  return true; 
  }
});
```

Comment: surely these selectors are overkill - you could simply use: var bottom = $("#text_box_bottom_range").val();

Answer (score 0):

this line

```
if ($("input[type='range'][id='text_box_bottom_range']").val() > this.val) {
```

should be

```
if ($("input[type='range'][id='text_box_bottom_range']").val() > $("input[type='range'][id='text_box_top_range']").val()) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your blur event on the input element to

```
$("input").blur(function() {
  if ($('#text_box_bottom_range').val() >= $('#text_box_top_range').val()) {
    console.log("bottom is equal or higher than the top");
    return false;
  } else { 
    return true; 
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#text_box_bottom_range").change(function() {
    return $(this).val();
});

$("#text_box_top_range").change(function() {
    return $(this).val();
});     

$("input").blur(function() {
    if ($("#text_box_bottom_range").val() =>  $("#text_box_top_range").val()) {
        return false;
    } else { 
        return true; 
    }
});
```

This does the correct check where bottom is:

> ...**equal** or **greater** than the top value

Also, the first 2 functions (`.change()`) are quite redundant for what you are trying to achieve but I've included a better way to write them